# setCacheQuery with HibernateTemplate for Named Queries

Tags: spring, hibernate

I want to use query cache with HibernateTemplate for a **named query** (**not HSQL Query**). And I am aware of using

```
getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true);
getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQuery(String queryName);
```

But I am worried about if my DAO does have multiple DAO methods but only in some cases I want to use cache and not for all. so when I use **getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true);** then will not it be applied for other DAO calls where I don't really need the query cache? When does it makes the *setCacheQueries(false)* ? I came across the question: [How is getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries() supposed to be used properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091618/how-is-gethibernatetemplate-setcachequeries-supposed-to-be-used-properly/7091871#7091871). But I need to use with namedQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Make two different instances of HibernateTemplate, one with setCacheQueries true and other with false. Use the instances according to your requirement

Comment: HibernateTemplate is provided by **org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport** class
through getHibernateTemplate() method. I do not have no scope of changing this instance.

Comment: Does it create a new hibernate session for each transaction or for each DAO call when getHibernateTemplate() is called, hibernatetemplate object will be created and used only for a single DAO call and will not be shared across other DAO calls? Please suggest.

Comment: getHibernateTemplate() returns you a instance of hibernateTemplate, so you can inject this instance in your service classes where you are access the dao classes which need the queries to be cached. In other classes use the another instance of Hibernate template. Also session does not start on calling getHibernateTemplate() method.

Comment: getHibernateTemplate() provides you an instance of the HibernateTemplate. You can always modify the properties of that instance